# Conversion of BUFR format into grib

Tags: data-formats, bufr

I am looking for Upper Air Observations (UAO) for Bay of Bengal region. I found NCEP ADP UAO dataset available in BUFR format. I am supposed to use UAO data in grib format only for the purpose of data assimilaion.

Is there any way, one can convert BUFR data into grib format?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps [GrADS](http://cola.gmu.edu/grads/downloads.php), which appears to be able to parse the data, combined with posts answering [this question](http://gradsusr.org/pipermail/gradsusr/2015-February/038092.html) on exporting results to GRIB???

Comment: thanks for replying but I am not familiar with GrADS. Secondly, I have also come to know that the observed data belongs to different stations, so it can not be converted into gridded format and hence in grib format.

Comment: Perhaps [this link](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/g2grb.html) can help you turn station data into grib.  Looks like the tools are still connected to GrADS?  I personally found GrADS pretty easy to pick it up when using it in years gone by, though indeed haven't used it in a while either.  But you may well be able to run that script without too many complications?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how I would do this. [ECMWF's ECCODES](https://confluence.ecmwf.int/display/ECC) has a tool called [bufr_ls](https://software.ecmwf.int/wiki/display/ECC/bufr_ls) and you can use that to  write the contents of that output to a text file. Then I would read that file into a scripting language such as Python and write out the contents as a GRIB file using [PyGrib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygrib). You can also explore the output of [bufr_dump](https://software.ecmwf.int/wiki/display/ECC/bufr_dump) and convert that also to GRIB if you wish. The full list of all BUFR format tools from ecCodes is given in this link [BUFR tools](https://software.ecmwf.int/wiki/display/ECC/BUFR+tools)
For more information regarding either of those softwares you can reach out to their support network and then get your doubts resolved.

**UPDATE**

If you want a 100 % Pythonic solution then you can try  [Python-Bufr](https://github.com/pytroll/python-bufr) which basically wraps ECMWF BUFR or use this python BUFR library - [bufrpy](http://bufrpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)